# Delphi - interface as another interface

Tags: delphi

I have two interfaces, ISomeInterfaceRO (read only) and ISomeInterface.

```
ISomeInterfaceRO = interface(IInterface) ['{B28A9FB0-841F-423D-89AF-E092FE04433F}']
function GetTest: Integer;
  property Test : integer read GetTest;
end;

ISomeInterface = interface(ISomeInterfaceRO) ['{C7148E40-568B-4496-B923-89BB891A7310}']
    procedure SetTest(const aValue: Integer);
    property Test : integer read GetTest write SetTest;
end;

TSomeClass = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterfaceRO, ISomeInterface)
private
    fTest: integer;
protected
  function GetTest: integer;
  procedure SetTest(const aValue: integer);
public
  property Test: integer read GetTest write SetTest;
end;

function TSomeClass.GetTest: integer;
begin
  Result := fTest;
end;

procedure TSomeClass.SetTest(const aValue: integer);
begin
  fTest := aValue;
end;
```

Then, i use read only interface except one place, when i create TSomeClass instance as ISomeInterface and fill it. example:

```
Function GetSome: ISomeInterfaceRO;
var
  SomeInterface: ISomeInterface;
begin
  SomeInterface := TSomeClass.Create;
  SomeInterface.Test := 10;
  result := SomeInterface as ISomeInterfaceRO;
end;
```

My question is: that "result := SomeInterface as ISomeInterfaceRO;" is a safe and recommended construction? Or is a another way to do this?
I debugged that code, and compiler properly decreased reference count to ISomeInterface and increased to ISomeInterfaceRO when i use "as".

Comment: It's not right to change the question after it has been answered. You should take your medicine and recognise the mistake. After all, I gave you fair warning of the problems over on G+. Now you need to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that for the future

Answer (score 4):

```
Result := SomeInterface as ISomeInterfaceRO;
```

is safe but not necessary at all because `ISomeInterface` inherits from `ISomeInterfaceRO` and thus `SomeInterface` is assignment compatible to `Result`. That means you can just write

```
Result := SomeInterface;
```

I however would put a constructor on `TSomeClass` that takes the value so you can directly write:

```
Result := TSomeClass.Create(10);
```

Comment: Hello Stefan!
Thank You for Your comment. I know that, my previous example code is not focusing necessary at my REAL question :)
So, i'll edit it, and remove inherit.